# A suggestion for using fix-effect in panel data with categorical dependent variable in R

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, panel-data

Currently, I'm analyzing data of concerts over 30 years which covers 10 rock bands in R. In doing so, I'm planning to run a logistic regression with fix-effects and clustered standard errors like:

```
model <- glm(DV ~ IV + band.name + year, family = binomial(link = "logit")
robust_se    <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type = "HC3", cluster="band.name")))
```

where my dependent variable is a dummy variable, and band.name and year (fix-effect part) are factor variables.

When I search on google if I'm right, I found some econometricians and statisticians calling this procedure end up in bias so that one should apply conditional logit in the case like this.

Can someone kindly give me a comment if the result of my original code is biased and suggest a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the link! What would you say if I use linear probability models (OLS) in this case?

Comment: yes you can start with OLS. The main issue is that it is possible that the model will return negative fitted values for some observations. In spite of this, it is used a lot.

Comment: Appreciated. I will go with OLS at this point.